# How to print the Correct output using " while loop "?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, while-loop

The Expected Output is 2000 but it stops on 1980.

> Note: The Execution is started from **20** and not from **0** as **int
>   i = 1**

The Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  const int iarraysize = 100;
  int i = 1;
  int iarray[iarraysize];
  while (i < iarraysize) {
    iarray[i] = 20 * i;
    cout << iarray[i++] << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @Ayxan yes it contains good information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last value of the variable `i` that is less than 100 is 99. So 20 * 99 is equal to `1990`.

If you want to get 2000 then rewrite the loop like

```
int i = 0;
while (i < iarraysize) {
  iarray[i] = 20 * (i + 1);
  cout << iarray[i++] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrays start at 0, and end one before their size.

You don't need an array however.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int limit = 100;
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= limit)
    {
        std::cout << (i++ * 20) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd make `limit` const. Besides that, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

The array goes from 0 to 99, you start at 1 and it only goes to 99 (99*20=1980).

You're expecting 2000 but there's no `iarray[100]` (array out of bounds).

Comment: I got 99 problems but the start index ain't 1 --- [sorry, it had to be done :)]

Comment: I know the feeling, Im having to use the GDPR manual for toilet paper just now due to a shortage in the supermarkets.